# Java Null Object or Object creation?

Tags: java, ruby-on-rails, hibernate

Is there an easier way in Java to create an object if a getter returns a null value?

For example, in RoR, if I recall correctly, something along these lines possible:

```
Obj myObj = getObjFromSomewhere() || new Obj();
```

which would set myObj to the object returned by the function, or a new Obj if that was null.

In Java, the easiest way I've found to do this is:

```
Obj myObj = (getObjFromSomewhere() != null ? getObjFromSomewhere() : new Obj());
```

or

```
Obj myObj = getObjFromSomewhere();
if(myObj == null) {
    myObj = new Obj()
}
```

Both are less than ideal, the first because it requires method calls, which is bad when dealing with a database, and the second just because its bulky.

Comment: `Obj myObj = ((myObj = getObjFromSomewhere()) != null ? myObj : new Obj());` is one line, but not exactly clear. I usually just go with your second strategy or write a method to provide an Obj if I'll be doing it often.

Comment: Two lines to avoid calling getObjFromSomewhere() more than once: `Obj temp = getObjFromSomewhere();    Obj myObj = (null == temp) ? new Obj() : temp;`

Answer (score 1):

I believe that you must make your code simpler:

The first sentence calls your method twice, which is unnecessary. 
The second option is clearly not bulky as you don't have other simpler way to make first option simpler.

What I would suggest is creating a utility if you feel like you will need to re-use this methodology over and over.

```
public class NotNullUtility {

    private NotNullUtility() {

    }

    public static <T> T select(T value, T defaultValue) {
        if (defaultValue == null)
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Default value must not be null.");

        if (value == null) {
            return defaultValue;
        }

        return value;
    }   
};

Obj obj = NotNullUtility.select(getObjFromSomewhere(), new Obj());
```

(Which is essentially your 2nd option).

Comment: Note that this does mean creating an object as the default even if it isn't necessary, which may or may not be trivial.

Answer (score 0):

The second is the right way to do it. I disagree that it's bulky. It's java, that's the language syntax.

Answer (score 0):

IMHO the most elegant way is to use an Optional class. (If you're using Java 8 or higher).

```
Obj myObj = Optional.ofNullable(getObjFromSomewhere()).orElse(new Obj())
```

So you've got a one line implementation and no need to call getObjFromSomewhere() twice or to assign it to variable.